# Is there any 2.4 GHz tuner ICs for SDR receivers?

Tags: software-defined-radio, receiver, microwave

I have a hackrf one sdr, which i use to transmit test signals.
I am using ISM bands, so I can omit transmitting my callsign, checking correct sub band (FM, digital) etc.
And one of most interesting bands is 2.4 GHz, the wifi band.

The problem is that i have only one SDR device capable of operation in that band - the hackrf itself.

But recently I have discovered a MAX2121(b) IC which I saw in a sat top box circuit diagram. And this chip is what I think I need - it downconverts frequencies from 800-2100 mhz to IQ signal.

The problem is that this chip's upper band limit is 2100 MHz, which is below 2400 MHz.

I tried to google "S band tuner ic" and found one which band starts from 2600 - still outside desired band.

So, the question is: is there any 2.4 ghz tuner ICs for SDR receivers?

Comment: Hint: the hackrf is open hardware; you can find extensive documentation on Great Scott Gadget's repos. It contains a tuner IC.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.rtl-sdr.com/receive-up-to-4-5-ghz-on-your-rtl-sdr-for-5-using-a-directv-downconverter/

Comment: You could try to reuse old MMDS converters. They operated in 2.1-2.3GHz or 2.5GHz, which is still not quite the desired frequency, but already closer.